# USB C - max current without negotiating PD

Tags: usb-c, usb-pd

I have a device that requires 5W @ 5VDC and want to convert it to USB C power. I am torn between a design that just has two 5.1 kΩ Pd resistors on the CCx lines or one that includes a PD negotiator (my weapon of choice is the CYPD3177).

I'm fairly strongly inclined to just go with the two resistors and leave it at that, after all, it seems like there are lots of examples of relatively high draw circuits just doing that (exhibit A is the Raspberry Pi 4).

Is there a strong pragmatic reason to include the PD controller for a 5V only dataless sink? What's the maximum 5V current one should draw without negotiating?

Comment: Discussed recently here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/511601/257313

Comment: A true USB-C host is obligated to supply either 7.5W or 15W without any negotiation, so you can (and should) skip the complexity of the PD controller.